# Removing all 0 values from Double Array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having some issues trying to remove all 0 values from an array in Java, the array is pre-defined with a maximum number of values being 50. If the user inputs 10 values then there are always 40 x 0's remaining in the table.

I am attempting to find the length of this array not including 0 values, so the length of the array should only be defined by values 1 and up.

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
double[] storedValues = {32.0,42.4,34.5,32.4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0...}
arrayLength = storedValues.length;
```

Currently, arrayLength will return "50" as that is the pre-defined size of my array. I am trying to make this return "4" as there are only 4 values over 0 in this array.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stream `storedValues`, filter for elements greater than `0` and then count. Like,

```
int count = (int) Arrays.stream(storedValues).filter(d -> d > 0).count();
```

Or, loop and count yourself

```
int count = 0;
for (double d : storedValues) {
    if (d > 0) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers and explanation. +1

Answer (score 2):

simply use this code :

```
 double[] storedValues = {32.0,42.4,34.5,32.4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
       int arrayLength=0;

       for (int i = 0; i < storedValues.length; i++) {
        if(storedValues[i] > 0){
            arrayLength++;
        }

    }
```

//arrayLength give you 4

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using streams:

```
Arrays.stream(storedValues).filter(v -> v != 0.0).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to avoid adding the zeros in the first place. If it's part of the prompt, then here's what you need to do:

```
public double[] RemoveZeros(double[] source)
{
    return source.Where(i => i != 0).ToArray();
}
```

This would search the array for zeros, and then remove them. Hope this helps, dude.

Comment: Wrong language: OP is asking about Java.